# Rules for solving inequalities with negative fractions

Tags: inequality, fractions

What are the algebraic rules for solving inequalities with negative signs and fractions like:

$$\frac{1}{x}<-\frac{1}{5}$$

Comment: always over $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @user190080 yes

Comment: Just in case you are not fully aware: You have the right to accept any answer you find which helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Whenever we take the inverse, and both sides are either positive or both sides are negative then  the inequality sign reverses; (if one is side is positive and one side is negative, then the sign stays the same.)
2. Whenever we multiply both sides by $-1$, the inequality sign reverses too.

Since you don´t know whether x is positive or negative, you need to consider both scenarios.

Answer (score 2):

If $x \in \mathbb{R}$, then
$\frac{1}{x} < -\frac{1}{5}$ iff $x > -5$ and iff $-x < 5$.

If you are seeking after the rule of thumb, here it is: whenever we take inverse of both sides, the inequality sign reverses; whenever we multiply both sides by $-1$, the inequality sign reverses too.